# how to splice or push new elements in a specific index with usestate?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, splice, use-state

I'm trying to insert new elements in the array and update the state base on the array, but the problem after I update the state It doesn't get rendered in the component.

- note: I'm not really sure how to use splice. ( I wanted the `handleClick` function to add new element under the clicked element but it seems I failed in that as well.)
- note 2: I also tried `setstate((pre) => { pre.splice(index + 1, 0, { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true }); return pre; });`  but didn't work as well.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let elements = [
    { id: 0, text: "first", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 1, text: "second", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 2, text: "third", autoFocus: true }
  ];
  const [state, setstate] = useState(elements);

  function handChange(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const x = state;
      const index = x.findIndex((item) => item.id == e.target.id);

      //i'm using autoFocus to move the focus  (I-beam pointer) to the nex field.
      //but i still get errors with it
      // e.map((item) => Object.assign(item, { autoFocus: false }));
      
      x.splice(index + 1, 0, { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true });
      console.log(state); // you can see this update probarly
      setstate(x); // but when I update state sometimes it don't render othertimes it take a while before render.

    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((e) => (
        // when I say it don't render I mean the e value don't get updated.
        <div
          focus={e.focus}
          contentEditable="true"
          id={e.id}
          onKeyUp={handChange}
        >
          {e.text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-silence-c1t1k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: How do you know when to update the item with what index?

Comment: by using `      const index = x.findIndex((item) => item.id == e.target.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
x.splice(index + 1, 0, { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true });
      setstate(x)
```

I replace it with this code

```
setstate((pre) => {
      
        return [
          ...pre.slice(0, index + 1),
          { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true },
          ...pre.slice(index + 1, state.length)
        ];
      })
```

that return the elements  before the element on the index `index + 1` + the new element + the elements after the element on the index `index + 1`

- for example, if you have 3 elements and you hit enter on the 2d element then the index is of it is `1` and you will a create a new element in the index `1+1` and after it, you will return the third element which is in the area between `1+1, 3` in which 3 is the length of the array.

## alternative explanation:

- `...pre.slice(0, index + 1),` this return all elements before the element that you hit enter in it + the element that you hit enter in it.
- `{ id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true },` this will create new elements after the previous elements
- `...pre.slice(index + 1, state.length)` this will return the elements after the element where you hited enter (in case of there is no it will return nothing)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `splice` like this to update your array.

```
const newArray = [...state];
newArray.splice(e.target.id, 0, newElement);
setstate(newArray);
```

Since `splice` mutates the original array. You could use a spread operator to create a new array and then apply splice to it.

This creates a new array with state in it.

```
[...state]
```

You could check the docs of splice [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: isn't state=[...state], they must be exactly the same and no need for ...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you can just write it like this `const newArray =state.splice(e.target.id, 0, newElement);`
`setstate(newArray)`

Comment: by the why, splice does not return newArray but it is edited the array.

Comment: My bad, got confused between splice and slice again, I've updated the code. Thanks for the clarification.